# How to properly call a variable for Get-WmiObject using a list of computers

Tags: powershell, foreach, get-wmiobject, computer-name

I'm trying to determine how to properly call a variable for Get-WmiObject using a list of computers.

No matter what I do I cannot get this code to work.

I have spent a few hours reviewing code to compile the code I have and feel like I'm 90% there but can't get past this last little thing. I'm also new to Powershell but am trying my butt off

```
$comp = Import-CSV .\testlist.csv 

foreach $comp{



    $cs = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $comp
    $bios = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_BIOS -ComputerName $comp
    $tpm = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\cimv2\security\microsofttpm -Class Win32_Tpm -computername $comp -Authentication PacketPrivacy
    $cos = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem -computername $comp | select-object Caption, BuildNumber, OSArchitecture

    $properties = [ordered]@{
        'ComputerName' = $comp;
        'Model' = $cs.Model;
        'Operating System' = $cos.Caption
        'OS build' = $cos.BuildNumber
        'OS Type' = $cos.OSArchitecture
        'BIOSVersion' = $bios.SMBIOSBIOSVersion
        'TPM ManufacturerId' = $tpm.ManufacturerId
        'TPM Firmware version' = $tpm.ManufacturerVersion
        'TPM SpecVersion' = $tpm.SpecVersion
        )


}| Export-Csv -Path .\Result.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Error Message:

> New Text Document.ps1:4 char:8
>   + foreach $comp{
>   +        ~ Missing opening '(' after keyword 'foreach'.
>
> New Text Document.ps1:4 char:14
>   + foreach $comp{
>   +              ~ Unexpected token '{' in expression or statement.
>
> New Text Document.ps1:22 char:39
>   +         'TPM SpecVersion' = $tpm.SpecVersion
>   +                                             ~ The hash literal was incomplete.
>
> New Text Document.ps1:4 char:14
>   + foreach $comp{
>   +              ~ Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
>
> New Text Document.ps1:23 char:3
>   +         )
>   +         ~ Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
>
> New Text Document.ps1:26 char:1
>   + }| Export-Csv -Path .\Result.csv -NoTypeInformation
>   + ~ Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
>
> New Text Document.ps1:26 char:2
>   + }| Export-Csv -Path .\Result.csv -NoTypeInformation
>   +  ~
>
> An empty pipe element is not allowed.
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingOpenParenthesisAfterKeyword

Comment: remove the parenthesis after $tpm.SpecVersion

Comment: [1] PLEASE fix your code formatting. ///// [2] this `foreach $comp{` is NOT how one calls a foreach loop. [*grin*] it should be something like `foreach ($Thing in $Collection) {Do-Stuff -With ParameterInfo}`.

Answer (score 0):

Some basic things I have changed:

- `ForEach` : if you don't use the () you can loop through the $comp using `Foreach-Object`:

`$comp | ForEach-Object  { write-host "computername: $_ "}` .

- No `;` at the end of the line :)
- Pipe every element to export csv and use `-append` (you were piping the final result)
- I prefer to use `convertTo-csv | out-file somefile.csv` . `Export-csv` is doing the same but applies some filters on the output that will sometimes make unexpected results

```bsh
foreach ($c in $comp) {
            $cs = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $c
            $bios = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_BIOS -ComputerName $c
            $tpm = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\cimv2\security\microsofttpm -Class Win32_Tpm -computername $c -Authentication PacketPrivacy
            $cos = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem -computername $c | select-object Caption, BuildNumber, OSArchitecture    
        $properties = [ordered]@{
            'ComputerName'         = $c
            'Model'                = $cs.Model
            'Operating System'     = $cos.Caption
            'OS build'             = $cos.BuildNumber
            'OS Type'              = $cos.OSArchitecture
            'BIOSVersion'          = $bios.SMBIOSBIOSVersion
            'TPM ManufacturerId'   = $tpm.ManufacturerId
            'TPM Firmware version' = $tpm.ManufacturerVersion
            'TPM SpecVersion'      = $tpm.SpecVersion
        }  | 
        Export-Csv -Path .\Result.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

After the  `}  |`  there is a back-tick character (  `  ) that tells powershell the line is broken in two . It was messing the formatting, so i removed it, don't forget to put it back.